# Git: disable read access on a per-branch basis for individual git users?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch, acl, readonly

### Summary

How can our team disable branch "read access" for individual git users? Does the market offer any existing tools for self-hosted environments? Or is there some other, better means to provide "disabled read access" to git files/directories?

Thus far, we think we might prefer git-branch-based access-control, as a) branch-based control seems better than b) directory-based control, as (a) seems able to do everything (b) can, and more.

We realize this is a tall order for a tool (git) that is designed to copy *everything* (in a repo) to a clone (of said repo). We're skeptical, but still curious to see if creative solutions exist or might be invented/discoverable.

### Preferred features

1. **RACL (read-access-control lists) for any branch,** including for unlimited # of any individual branches for any set or combination of git users.
2. **[Optional] Integration with *any* git repo client/server software**. This way we can theoretically integrate with most any git-based tool/ecosystem. However if a special/custom git tool set is required, we'll explore using that.
3. **[Optional] Seamless GitLab integration**. We do not yet see GitLab offering this feature. (We do not yet see protected branches with a "disable reads" feature.)
4. **[Optional] Self-hosted git repo**. We self-host services, including git, for our critical projects whenever possible. But we'll consider working with hosted services if that's the only way, for now.

### More details

We've not yet empirically tested any of the claimed features from various, self-hosting-feature tool providers. [But we've performed a tiny bit of research](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/johnnyutahh/42ae2141bfb46fdc3a5f58a02af531e5/raw). Nothing we've seen yet outright claims features for "disabled-read privacy"; [Gitolite](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/overview.html#why-might-you-need-it) maybe does?

There seems to be more market focus on "protecting" branches to avoid data-loss scenarios. Instead, with this discussion, I'm more interested in preventing (read) access of designated users to sensitive information.

One could make a different git repo for each "group/class" of access, but that's problematic for numerous reasons, including but not limited to:

- requiring a theoretically unlimited number of repos for each combination of private info as an organization scales.
- an inability to tightly-couple private with "full group" information when requiring separate git repos simply to "wall them off" from each other for intra-group privacy.

Enabling unlimited "private" git branches within a common, larger repo seems like a more-effective path.

Comment: Git is designed to prevent doing what you want to do. Any system that attempts to add read access control is going to have to slog through a lot of issues.

Comment: Got it @torek. If that's true, let's see who can or how we can do the slog. Or come up with some other kind of workaround. It's a big, big problem for broader, corporate-documentation repos that have financial, HR, and other sensitive info in them. Subversion does this just fine, fwiw.

Comment: Git hosting solutions have per-repository access control. It may have per-branch **push** control, but since git is a distributed system, there is no control locally on the client computer that limits what that person can do. If you want to section off parts of your code or data, don't store it all in one repository.

Comment: If the files aren't needed for day-to-day developing, why are they stored in the same repository as the files that are needed?

Comment: For sure, a hosted system **could** have access control which disallowed read/visibility access to certain branches, and by extension all the commits which are only available through them, but I have yet to see any such system in place. It **will** have to be server-side though, as again, git locally have no access control at all. If you have the repo, you have full access to all you got. The question that could be answered differently is **what did you get from the server?**

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - I'm not yet sure how frequency of access has a bearing. Consider a complete "documentation" repository for a larger corporation instead of a code-only repo. Imagine adding "private comments" to an existing document(s) for a discussion within a smaller group before merging a said private branch (and probably only its "blessed" commits, and not all its commits) back into the full-group-public repo/branches. This is not the only scenario class we want to serve, but it might (or might not) help expand/describe the scope in a way to better answer your question(s).

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - we understand the solution, given current git software, will probably need to be server-side focused.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution with Gitlab to limit write-access is:

- protect the branches.
- request contribution though merge request (meaning fork)

But to limit *read* access, you need a separate repository, private, which will include the private branches.

Anything in your public repository is be definition readable.

Comment: Protecting the branches will limit push access, it will not limit **access** to the files and data in those branches, which is what I understand OP wants.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Correct. I have rewritten the answer accordingly.

Comment: I have also edited the question to make GitLab integration optional. Does removing the GitLab requirement possibly enable more options (towards finding a solution)?

Comment: @JohnnyUtahh No: anything private must be dealt with a separate repository, whatever the Hosting repository server is (GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, Gitea, ...). Anything else is way too risky/finicky, and will lead to confidential data leaking.

Comment: @VonC - understood. And makes perfect sense. I've updated the question to reflect the potential "impossibility" of this request given current git technology.

Comment: @JohnnyUtahh "git technology" is limited to *distributed* data: no authentication, no authorization. So the quick fix is: separate private repo for private branches.

Comment: @VonC - yep, we get it about private repos for private pranches. And that's what we do today. And it's cumbersome. And we realize that's today's limits. Separately, we'd love to enable non-server-side-admin users with a means to on-demand and immediately "branch for privacy." We can (en)vision possible future git-client extensions (or maybe just different, "impure" git clients) that automatically handle forking private branches into separate repos on the server side, but we have not yet seen any such solution currently provide this capability.

Comment: @JohnnyUtahh Today, editing a file in another owner repository triggers a fork automatically (https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/editing-files-in-another-users-repository). That could be a start.

Comment: @VonC - this "automatic fork trigger" feature (in github, at least) is quite interesting. Great reference, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Gitlab, you could use Gerrit (https://www.gerritcodereview.com/)
 which allows you to enable ACL read access per reference  (https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#_project_access_control_lists)

As an example, to allow private/public sandbox for each registered user:

Repository "All-Projects", "Access":

**Reference**:refs/*
remove Read for Anonymous Users

**Reference**:^refs/heads/users/.+/public/.+
Allow Read "Registered Users"

**Reference**:refs/heads/users/${username}/public/*
Allow Create Reference, Delete Reference, Push (w/ or w/o force), Read for Registered Users

**Reference**:refs/heads/users/${username}/private/*
Allow Create Reference, Delete Reference, Push (w/ or w/o force), Read for Registered Users

I don't know if it's possible to use the special "${username}" with the regexp to write only one rule.